# How to get a variable value from Environment files in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm deploying my first Phoenix Application, and I've specified the values of a variable in my Environment Files (`dev.exs` and `prod.exs`).

Now I'm trying to figure out how to access them in my Controllers.

```elixir
# config/dev.exs
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  cache_static_lookup: false,
  my_var: "DEVELOPMENT VALUE"

# config/prod.exs
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [host: "example.com"],
  my_var: "PRODUCTION VALUE"
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Okay, found something. [Elixir's](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html) `Application.get_env/3` is the way to go:

> **[get_env(app, key, default \\ nil)](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#get_env/3)**

---

But the problem with this is that the accessor command becomes very long for the current situation:

```elixir
# Set value in config/some_env_file.exs
config :my_large_app_name, MyLargeAppName.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [host: "example.com"],
  my_var: "MY ENV VARIABLE"

# Get it back
Application.get_env(:my_large_app_name, MyLargeAppName.Endpoint)[:my_var]
```

---

***A better way*** would be to define them in a separate section:

```elixir
config :app_vars,
  a_string: "Some String",
  some_list: [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3], 
  another_bool: true
```

and access them like this:

```elixir
Application.get_env(:app_vars, :a_string)
# => "Some String"
```

Or you could fetch a `list` of all key-value pairs:

```elixir
Application.get_all_env(:app_vars)           
# => [a_string: "Some String", some_list: [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3], another_bool: true]
```

Comment: About "accessor command becomes very long": You can always write a wrapper function around a long line of code that you repeat often.

Comment: Defining them under a different, smaller app name could be another option. See the updated answer.

Comment: You should only define application configurations for applications that you own. If you do `config :not_actuall_an_app, :key, :value`, it is not supported and it may break in some situations.

Comment: Env variables are supposed to be secret...? wouldn't putting them directly into `config.exs` be making them available in source control and therefore defeating the purpose of an env variable?

Comment: Not necessarily @thedanotto. I might simply need to use different values for different environments, secret or not.

Comment: I found this to be helpful because it allows me to keep my creds out of source control - http://blog.danielberkompas.com/elixir/2015/03/21/manage-env-vars-in-elixir.html  ... but it is possibly deviating from the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

I had some bug with @sheharyar solution, so here mean:

I had to create new block without `MyLargeAppName.Endpoint,`

```
# Set value in config/some_env_file.exs
config :my_large_app_name,
  my_var: "MY ENV VARIABLE"
```

and then in your code

```
Application.get_env(:my_large_app_name, :my_var)
```

WARNING: as @José Valim said you can not set any name as key `:my_large_app_name` it have to be the same of your project