# Load environment variable in template file in Phoenix Framework

Tags: templates, elixir, phoenix-framework

In a controller, I can load environment variables defined in config.exs using [Application.get_env/3.](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#get_env/3)

Is it possible to do load an environment variable directly inside a template file, aside from passing it through a controller? In particular, I'd like to load it in one of the layout files.

Comment: Why not just call `Application.get_env/3` from the template? `<%= Application.get_env(:my_app, :foo) %>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995743/how-to-get-a-variable-value-from-environment-files-in-phoenix) from 2015 will be helpful. As Dogber said, [Application.get_env/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#get_env/3) will do exactly what you want even in a template. Take a look at the template [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Template.html). Variables take the form:

```
<p><%= @key %></p>
```

So, you can do the following:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h3>This is h3 text</h3>

  <%= Application.get_env(:sheldonkreger_app, :some_env_var) %>
</div>
```

Phoenix uses Elixir [EEx templates](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html) so the above gets built at compile time and is safe and ready to use in your app.